# How to navigate pages without navigation stack in master detail page?

Tags: c#, xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I've created a PCL project where I'm having a main page where the person can navigate to three sections and each seciton has a login page. After logging in the master detail page comes which has number of pages to navigate.

```
Navigation Page
  Main Page (can be popped)   
   Login (can be popped)    
    Master Page
     Detail Page
      Navigation Page
       SubPages
```

When I'm navigating to detail pages, then it shows the error that android can't have two navigation stacks. How should I navigate to master page without navigation page or what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly set the `MainPage` of the `App` class when you are showing your main page or login page, and wrap your detail page in NavigationPage.

```
//show main page 
MainPage = new MyMainPage();

//show login page
MainPage = new LoginPage ();

//show master detail 
MainPage = new MyMasterDetailPage
           {
               MasterPage = new MyMasterPage()
               DetailPage = new NavigationPage(MyDetailPage)   
           }
```

Comment: Thanks, lots of love for you :)